# How to ask a user to define a path to download in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried searching but didn't get the right question/answer. I would like to construct/organize a zip in a path the user predefines. How is it possible to open a prompt dialog in JS and pick the path of the directory selected by the user. I use ruby on rails, jquery/javacript.

Comment: You have to use a Flash plugin for this.. because most browsers have their default Download location. It works if the you enable "Ask where to save each file before downloading".  But then again it depends on the browser settings.

Comment: If you're trying to access the local file system with javascript, you're screwed. Browsers don't allow this for security reasons.

Comment: for security reasons...you cannot do it...rather make a common folder and dump the file there asking user to visit that path once dumping is done...because all you need is to provide a file dumped by application...

Comment: @Milind What do you mean by "common folder"? Is there a common folder for all OSs ?